# Laravel 7 pdf, This page isn’t working and is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, laravel-7

My Laravel 7 application PDF was working perfectly on localhost but on the internet server it gives me this error -> This page isn’t working and is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500. Each time I download it back to the local server it will still work like always, and kept on giving me the same errors on the internet server. please how can I solve this?

Controller file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Models\Branch;
use App\Models\Product;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
use Auth;

class StockReportController extends Controller
{

public function stockReportPdf(Request $request){
        if (!Auth::user()->can('view_stock')) {
            return redirect('home')->with(denied());
        } // end permission checking

        $products = Product::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();

        $random_string = str_random(10);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('backend.pdf.reports.stock.all-branch', compact('products', 'request'))->setPaper('a4');

        if ($request->action_type == 'download'){
            return $pdf->download('stock-report-' . Carbon::now()->format(get_option('app_date_format')) . '-'. $random_string . '.pdf');
        }elseif($request->action_type == 'print'){
            @unlink('pdf/reports/stock/' . 'stock-report.pdf');
            $pdf->save('pdf/reports/stock/' . 'stock-report.pdf');
            return redirect('pdf/reports/stock/' . 'stock-report.pdf');
        }else{

            $headers = [
                'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
                , 'Content-type' => 'text/csv'
                , 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=galleries.csv'
                , 'Expires' => '0'
                , 'Pragma' => 'public'
            ];

            $filename = 'download.csv';
            $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
            fputcsv($handle, [
                __('pages.sl'),
                __('pages.product'),
                __('pages.purchase') . ' '. __('pages.quantity'),
                __('pages.sells') . ' '. __('pages.quantity'),
                __('pages.current_stock_quantity'),
                __('pages.current_stock_value'),
            ]);

            $products = Product::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {

                if (Auth::user()->can('access_to_all_branch')) {
                   $purchaseQuantity = $product->purchaseProducts->sum('quantity');
                    $sellQuantity = $product->sellProducts->sum('quantity');
                    $current_stock_qty = $product->purchaseProducts->sum('quantity') - $product->sellProducts->sum('quantity');
                } else {
                    $purchaseQuantity = $product->purchaseProducts->where('branch_id', auth()->user()->employee->branch_id)->sum('quantity');
                    $sellQuantity = $product->sellProducts->where('branch_id', auth()->user()->employee->branch_id)->sum('quantity');
                    $current_stock_qty =  productAvailableTransactionStockQty($product->id);
                }

                $product_tax = $product->sell_price * $product->tax->value / 100;
                $current_stock_amount = $current_stock_qty * ($product->sell_price + $product_tax);


                fputcsv($handle, [
                    $key + 1,
                    $product->title . '|'. $product->sku,
                    $purchaseQuantity,
                    $sellQuantity,
                    $current_stock_qty,
                    get_option('app_currency') . number_format($current_stock_amount,2),
                ]);
            }

            fclose($handle);
            return response()->download($filename, 'stock-report-' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.csv', $headers);

        }
    }

    private function branchRequisitionFromQty($request, $product){
        $branch_requisitions_from = \App\Models\Requisition::where('requisition_from', $request->branch_id)
            ->where('status', 2)
            ->select('id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();

        return $branch_requisitions_from_qty = \App\Models\RequisitionProduct::whereIn('requisition_id', $branch_requisitions_from)
            ->where('product_id', $product->id)
            ->sum('quantity');
    }

    private function branchRequisitionToQty($request, $product){
        $branch_requisitions_to = \App\Models\Requisition::where('requisition_to', $request->branch_id)
            ->where('status', 2)
            ->select('id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();

      return  $branch_requisitions_to_qty = \App\Models\RequisitionProduct::whereIn('requisition_id', $branch_requisitions_to)
            ->where('product_id', $product->id)
            ->select('id')
            ->sum('quantity');
    }
}
```

Blade Template file

```
<div class="card-header p-0">
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified nav-buttons" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <a href="{{url('report/stock-report')}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary {{ active_if_full_match('report/stock-report') }}"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> Stock Summary </a>
                    </div>

         <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm filter-pdf-btn" role="group">
         <form action="{{url('report/stock-report-pdf')}}" method="get">
         <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="download">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0 btn-sm pl-2 pr-2"><i class="fas fa-file-download mr-2"></i> {{__('pages.pdf')}} </button>
         </form>

         <form action="{{url('report/stock-report-pdf')}}" method="get" target="_blank">
         <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="print">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm rounded-0 pl-2 pr-2"><i class="fa fa-print mr-2"></i> {{__('pages.print')}} </button>
         </form>

         <form action="{{url('report/stock-report-pdf')}}" method="get">
         <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="csv">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm rounded-0 pl-2 pr-2"><i class="fa fa-file-csv mr-2"></i> {{__('pages.csv')}} </button>
         </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A 500 error basically says "Its serious" Look for clues in the error logs

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just checked the error log, it says the file is empty

Comment: Then you need to make sure that logging is turned on

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is on I could see normal logs for today and in the error log section I could also see the one for yesterday, but today's own is empty.

Comment: @Olu-Stephen I'm having the same issue, working with less data but for large data, it gives the above error and nothing is there in the log file! have you found any solution?

Comment: @SouravDutt No, I haven't. Have you?